# After installing libmamba solver i get `warning libmamba Could not parse state file`

Tags: conda, mamba

With `Anaconda` and `Mamba` installed, I now came across the `libmamba-solver`, which is quite officially recommended on the Anaconda blog as the standard solver for conda.

After I followed exactly the instructions on

```
https://www.anaconda.com/blog/a-faster-conda-for-a-growing-community
```

I get with every `conda update (something)`
first several warnings of the form

```
warning libmamba Could not parse state file:
```

These warnings even occur when using
`mamba update (something)`

Here is the complete output:

```
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
warning  libmamba Could not parse state file: Could not load cache state: [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be l
warning  libmamba Could not remove state file "C:\\Users\\Mathias\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\cache\\59ba4880.state.json": Der Pr.
warning  libmamba Could not parse state file: Could not load cache state: [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be l
warning  libmamba Could not remove state file "C:\\Users\\Mathias\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\cache\\3e39a7aa.state.json": Der Pr.
warning  libmamba Could not parse state file: Could not load cache state: [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be l
warning  libmamba Could not remove state file "C:\\Users\\Mathias\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\cache\\920c960f.state.json": Der Pr.
warning  libmamba Could not parse state file: Could not load cache state: [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be l
warning  libmamba Could not remove state file "C:\\Users\\Mathias\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\cache\\4ea078d6.state.json": Der Pr.
warning  libmamba Could not parse state file: Could not load cache state: [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be l
warning  libmamba Could not remove state file "C:\\Users\\Mathias\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\cache\\5ca77eed.state.json": Der Pr.
warning  libmamba Could not parse state file: Could not load cache state: [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be l
warning  libmamba Could not remove state file "C:\\Users\\Mathias\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\cache\\c4a505b4.state.json": Der Pr.
pkgs/r/win-64                                      742.8kB @   2.4MB/s  0.4s
pkgs/main/noarch                                   819.6kB @   2.2MB/s  0.4s
pkgs/msys2/noarch                                  111.0 B @ 293.0 B/s  0.1s
pkgs/msys2/win-64                                   39.8kB @  79.3kB/s  0.1s
pkgs/r/noarch                                        1.3MB @   1.8MB/s  0.4s
pkgs/main/win-64                                     4.7MB @   3.9MB/s  1.5s
conda-forge/noarch                                  11.5MB @   3.4MB/s  4.1s
conda-forge/win-64                                  19.5MB @   2.8MB/s  8.4s
Collect all metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - conda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-23.1.0               |   py39hcbf5309_0         912 KB  conda-forge
    jupyter_server_fileid-0.8.0|     pyhd8ed1ab_0          19 KB  conda-forge
    y-py-0.5.9                 |   py39hf21820d_0         460 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         1.4 MB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  jupyter_server_fi~                     0.7.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 --> 0.8.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  y-py                                 0.5.5-py39hf21820d_2 --> 0.5.9-py39hf21820d_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  conda              pkgs/main::conda-23.1.0-py39haa95532_0 --> conda-forge::conda-23.1.0-py39hcbf5309_0


Proceed ([y]/n)?


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

You can see that an update can be done despite the `warning`.
So the first question is how much the warning means at all and if it is a problem.
It is of course annoying, but is there an actual problem?
And if so, how can it be fixed?

Comment: This is discussed in https://github.com/conda/conda-libmamba-solver/issues/145

Comment: but still there is no solutin?

Comment: It does not seem to major affect things. For me the warning stopped, no idea why. Maybe because of a `conda clean --all` call?

Comment: @MatteoFerla `conda clean --all` fixed it for me.

Comment: `conda clean -i`  (`-i` for `--index-cache`) was enough for me.