# How do I solve a dysgu installation error where I receive libmamba Problem type not implemented?

Tags: installation, conda, mamba

I am attempting to install [dysgu](https://github.com/kcleal/dysgu#installation) by creating a new dysgu conda environment and then installing dysgu within that environment, as suggested.

```
conda install -c bioconda -c conda-forge dysgu
```

However I am running into a libmamba error:

```
Channels:
- bioconda
- conda-forge 
- defaults
- r

Platform: linux-64

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment: | warning  libmamba Problem type not implemented SOLVER_RULE_STRICT_REPO_PRIORITY

warning  libmamba Problem type not implemented SOLVER_RULE_STRICT_REPO_PRIORITYPlatform: linux-64> warning  libmamba Problem type not implemented SOLVER_RULE_STRICT_REPO_PRIORITY ... 

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package dysgu-1.6.0-py310h770aed0_0 requires htslib >=1.18,<1.19.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed Could not solve for environment specs 

The following packages are incompatible 

└─ dysgu is not installable because there are no viable options    
   ├─ dysgu [1.3.16|1.4.0|1.4.2|1.5.0] would require
   │  └─ htslib [>=1.16,<1.19.0a0 |>=1.17,<1.19.0a0 ] but there are no viable options  
   │     ├─ htslib [1.17|1.18] would require    
   │     │  └─ libdeflate >=1.18,<1.20.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;    
   │     └─ htslib [1.16|1.17] would require
   │        └─ libdeflate >=1.13,<1.20.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;    
   ├─ dysgu 1.6.0 would require    
   │  └─ htslib >=1.18,<1.19.0a0 , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);    
   └─ dysgu [1.6.0|1.6.1] would require
      └─ pysam >=0.19  but there are no viable options
         ├─ pysam [0.19.0|0.19.1] would require
         │  └─ libdeflate >=1.10,<1.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
         ├─ pysam [0.19.1|0.20.0|0.21.0] would require
         │  └─ libdeflate >=1.13,<1.14.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
         └─ pysam 0.21.0 would require  
           └─ libdeflate >=1.18,<1.19.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.
```

I am wondering if this is a mamba/conda error? I followed the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75703897/after-installing-libmamba-solver-i-get-warning-libmamba-could-not-parse-state-f) and cleared my old cache by running the command:

```
conda clean --all
```

But had no success. Does anyone have additional suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: Please rerun with and report the results of `conda create -n dysgu -c conda-forge -c bioconda dysgu`. The Conda Forge channel should be first, and using `create` helps ensure the environment really is fresh. Otherwise, we can't tell confidently where the error is from. `conda info` output may be helpful. Also, please don't call something an "error" when it is clearly a "warning" - those are semantically different.